# How to handle OnRowClick event of ASPxGridView in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am using ASP.Net with VB to display records in a grid view.
In a normal ASP GridView, I can simply handle SelectedIndexChanged Event from code behind like this:

```
Sub mySub(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
          Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Dim id as String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Item(0).ToString
  Response.Redirect("Customer.aspx?ID=" & id) 'Or Whatever
End Sub
```

Now I am trying to do the same but with ASPxGridView that comes with DevExpress. Obviosly, there is no built in Event that can be handled directly from code behind. I have to go through client click with javascript, which I don't mind to but all my attempts to pass the click event from the client to the server code behind failed.

Here is my ASP page

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     KeyFieldName="id" Width="550px" OnSelectionChanged="row_selected" >
    <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" />
    <SettingsText Title="Customers" />
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="id" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <Settings ShowTitlePanel="True" />
    <ClientSideEvents FocusedRowChanged="function(s, e) {
        row_selected();
        }" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

And here is my code behind (Which never gets called)

```
Sub row_selected()
    Dim id as String = ASPxGridView1.SelectedRow.Item(0).ToString
    Response.Redirect("Customers.aspx?ID=" & id) 
End Sub
```

How can I call a function from code behind by clicking on a row on ASPxGridView row?

Comment: You say that you have managed to get the client side click event to work? Have you thought about setting up a handler to respond to the click event rather than code behind on the .aspx web page. If you did an AJAX call in your javascript you could make a request to the handler and receive a response.

Comment: @markp3rry I want to do a few steps before redirecting the user to another page. That can't be done from client side. I need to trigger the event in the server. I don't know how

Comment: The handler would run server side. Do some reading on generic handlers in .NET (you should be able to add it to your Visual Studio project, it has a .ashx extension) and how to call them from javascript.

Comment: @markp3rry Generic Handlers will only be convenient in redirecting the user to other URLs. What I need to do before redirecting the user is run some code, store some values to the database, fetch some information, calculate figures, then go to that page. That is why I need the code behind function to run from the .VB file

Comment: Wrong. I use them in quite a few different applications. You can feed data into them from a web page via HttpContext, run all the server side stuff you need and then post a response. I am looking at one that I wrote right now, it takes five input parameters, inserts these into a database via SqlCommand and returns a response in text/xml format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
1. Set [ASPxGridView1.SettingsBehavior.ProcessFocusedRowChangedOnServer](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewBehaviorSettings_ProcessFocusedRowChangedOnServertopic) to true.
2. Handle server side [FocusedRowChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FocusedRowChangedtopic) event

Comment: Very close, but you are right. I enabled SelectionChange instead and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want..

In my case,

I want to get contents of a field ('ID') from ASPxGridView when the user clicks on the row...

Create the ClientSideEvent for row click and put "RowClick(s, e);" in the function.

Create the actual function the event will call as shown below - and here is the tricky part;

do not use GetFocusedRowIndex() to get the index because it is the FOCUSED index.

Use e.visibleIndex

```
function RowClick(s, e) {
    // Do callback to get the row data for 'ID' using current row.
    MyAspxGridView.GetRowValues(e.visibleIndex, 'ID', OnGetRowId);
}
```

Create your call back to get the field you want. I'm getting 'ID'.

```
function OnGetRowId(idValue) {
    alert('ID: ' + idValue.toString());
}
```